# Navigation drawer in android fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created navigation drawer in a separate class and extended that activity to a fragment. Navigation drawer is working fine in that fragment. And I am switching the content of the fragment using FragmentManager.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("content")) {
            String content = savedInstanceState.getString("content");
            if (content.equals(FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                    setFragmentTitle(R.string.favorites);
                    contentFragment = fragmentManager
                            .findFragmentByTag(FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                }
            }
        }
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ProductListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
            pdtListFragment = (ProductListFragment) fragmentManager
                    .findFragmentByTag(ProductListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
            contentFragment = pdtListFragment;
        }
    } else {
        pdtListFragment = new ProductListFragment();
        setFragmentTitle(R.string.app_name);
        switchContent(pdtListFragment, ProductListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
    }
```

Navigation drawer is visible in ProductListFragment but on clicking FavoriteListFragment it is overlapped by that fragment. How to resolve that? I need to get the drawer in both ProductListFragment  and FavoriteListFragment

Comment: You really should use the NavigationDrawer in your activity, not in your fragment.

Comment: Then how do I get the drawer in fragment?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, would you explain a bit further ?

Comment: You can learn how to use navigation drawer with fragments here - androhub.com/android-navigationdrawer/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [**MaterialDrawer**](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library by [Mike Penz](https://plus.google.com/+MikePenz). Simple and powerful API. Just browse the [samples](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/tree/develop/app) to examine the lib.